# Mapstruct not mapped 'addLine1' field

Tags: mapstruct

'''
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ServiceAddress {
private String addLine1;
private String addLine2;
private String city;
private String state;
private String country;
private String zip;
private String zipCodeExtension;
}

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OrderDTO {
private List<OrderElement> orderElement;

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class OrderElement {

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
return o == this;
}

private ServiceAddress serviceAddress;

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class ServiceAddress {
private String addLine1;
private String addLine2;
private String city;
private String state;
private String country;
private String zip;
}
}
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface test {
ServiceAddress toServiceAddress(OrderDTO.OrderElement.ServiceAddress serviceAddress);
}

@Override
public lib.dao.dto.externalconnector.onebill.ServiceAddress toServiceAddress(ServiceAddress serviceAddress) {
if ( serviceAddress == null ) 
return null;
}

ServiceAddressBuilder serviceAddress1 = lib.dao.dto.externalconnector.onebill.ServiceAddress.builder();

serviceAddress1.city( serviceAddress.getCity() );
serviceAddress1.state( serviceAddress.getState() );
serviceAddress1.country( serviceAddress.getCountry() );
serviceAddress1.zip( serviceAddress.getZip() );

return serviceAddress1.build();
}
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why a property like `addLine1` is not mapped is due to the fact that it is treated as an adder for a list property `line1`.

You can either name that setter `setAddLine1` or disable the builder support (and MapStruct will use the `setAddLine1` from the DTO).